# Trying to understand strange behavior of format specifier in printf

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I saw that the as I keep increasing the value in format specifier "10s" to "100s" "1000s"  I get the output which keeps on shifting on the screen

```
main()
{
char s[]="Hello,,world";
printf("%10s",s);
}
```

**Output**

*`10s`*

```
Hello,,worldPress any key to continue . . .
```

*`100s`*

```
      Hello,,worldPress any key to continue . . .
```

*`1000s`*

```
                        Hello,,worldPress any key to continue . . .
```

What is happening ?

Comment: It's not strange at all if it's behaving exactly as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In printf , Giving the values in the format scpecifier, acts as giving the leading spaces before printing the output. Count of the array value will be taken.

In first case,

```
Total array count is 12. You gave 10. So there is no leading spaces.
```

In second and third case,

```
You gave 100, SO 100-12=88 spaces and 1000-12=988 spaces is given as a  output.
```

Only numeric in the control string it will give you the leading spaces.

Answer (score 2):

while using the `printf("%10s",s);` 
10s will be leave the leading spaces before the string. Your string has 12 characters, if you give 10s the length of the sting is greater than the integer, so there is no white space.

if the integer value is greater than the string then it will leave the white space.
while giving 100s, the length of the sting is less than the integer, so it leaves the whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Statement `printf("%ns",s);` prints the string `s`, but with a width `%nd` to say that we want `n` characters (positions) reserved for the output. The result is that `n` space characters are placed before printing the character.

Comment: `printf("<%8d>",-123);` --> `<____-123>`.  Only 4 spaces placed before printing `-123`, not 8. `_` substituted for ` `